# d3 v4 - drag 'clickDistance' doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 element 'itemGroup' which has other elements within it. One of these is a text label that I'd like to subscribe to the click events of.

Additionally, I'd like the itemGroup to be draggable. Without the code below the click events fire as expected. With the below code I get the drag behaviour I want, but the click event on the child element of itemGroup no longer fires.

```
d3.selectAll(".itemGroup").call(d3.drag().clickDistance(4).on("start", started));
```

I thought that 'clickDistance' was meant to address this but setting any large or small value doesn't seem to have any effect. I expected a value of '4' to mean that the drag behaviour wouldn't kick in until 4 or more distance units have been travelled by the mouse (in the mousedown state), but I see the drag behaviour start immediately.

Tried with 4, 40, 4000.... nothing changes the behaviour. I'm on the [latest and greatest version to date](https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js).

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, set up a [MCVE] reproducing the issue. By the way, `clickDistance` is used for having **both** click and drag working. You can still listen to a click in the child with distance set to zero: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XezRGX

Comment: Many thanks to @Gerardo Furtado, for poking me and telling me not to be lazy :-). Seriously, I completely agree with your Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example reference.

In fairness, I wasn't sure I was using the API correctly as the docs aren't great - to type information on params etc. Thanks also for clarifying the click AND drag behaviour.

Comment: Anyway, the codepen you provided worked a treat and I couldn't reproduce the issue there. On reflection of my own code I saw that I was clearing the svg and re-rendering everything on the drag end (which is firing before the click handler). This was what was causing the issue for me. I still need to do that, but a strategically placed setTimeout wrapping the refresh allows the click handler to fire before it's (presumably) cleaned up.

Many thanks!