# Both click and drag event listener on the same element. Click event not firing. + Data structure in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, click, drag

First of all, to keep my data alive with d3.js, I've got my data as follow
`let data = { ... }`. With this data, I draw mainly rectangles, nested in svg "g" tag. (The goal is to make a floor plan editor). Every change in "data" will fire my `drawIt()` function... charged to draw the data every time something changed (à la React, useState, ...). Data changes are made by moving, dragging, resizing those svg elements created by this data itself.

What do you think about this way of doing data visualisation with D3.js ?

Next, I think this way of handling data is the cause of my problem. 
I have an element ('rect') with a drag() behaviour as well as a click event listener. 
The click event is never called, because the drag event intercept the mousedown event. I don't know how I could make it work. I noticed that if I comment out the drag().on('end', function()), the click event is triggerd. So I think this is because my drawIt() is fired and then every element is re-created, and so on ... Actually I don't know. The thing is that this drawIt() function is also used in the d3.drag().on('drag', ...), and the click event is working good.

Here is my code. Have a look at the drawIt() , the d3.drag() called on '.surface

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-drag.v1.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-color.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-ease.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-interpolate.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-timer.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-transition.v1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>



<script src="draw.js"></script>
</body>
```

draw.js

```
//Make an SVG Container

let width = screen.width-200
let height = screen.height-300

let rooms = []

var plan = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                     .attr("width", width)
                                     .attr("height", height)
                                     .attr("transform", "translate(60, 60)")

let background = plan.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('fill', "lightblue")   
    .attr('id', "background")

function handleMouseOver() {
    d3.select(this).classed("foo", true);
    d3.select(this).style("cursor", 'all-scroll')
}

function handleMouseOut() {
    d3.select(this).classed("foo", false);
}

function drawIt(data) {
  console.log("drawit")
  plan.selectAll('g').remove()

  let room = 
    plan
      .selectAll('.room')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('g')

    room
        .attr('id', d => d.id)
        .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.tx} , ${d.ty})`)

    room
      .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', -5)
        .attr('width', d => d.w)
        .attr('height', 5)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
        .attr('class', 'handle n')
    room
      .append('rect')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', d => d.h)
        .attr('width', d => d.w)
        .attr('height', 5)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
        .attr('class', 'handle s')
    room
      .append('rect')
        .attr('x', -5)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 5)
        .attr('height', d => d.h)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
        .attr('class', 'handle w')
    room
      .append('rect')
        .attr('x', d => d.w)
        .attr('y', 0)
        .attr('width', 5)
        .attr('height', d => d.h)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
        .attr('class', 'handle e')
    room
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', 0)
        .attr('cy', 0)
        .attr('r', 4.8)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
    room
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.h)
        .attr('r', 4.8)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
    room
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d=>d.w)
        .attr('cy', d=>d.x)
        .attr('r', 4.8)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')
    room
      .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d=>d.w)
        .attr('cy', d=>d.h)
        .attr('r', 4.8)
        .attr('fill', 'grey')

    room    
      .append("rect")
        .attr('width', d => d.w)
        .attr('height', d => d.h )
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .attr('class', 'surface')

    d3.selectAll('.surface')
      .call(d3.drag()
      .on('start', dragStarted)
      .on("drag", dragRoom)
      .on("end", release))
      .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver) 
      .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut) 

    d3.selectAll('.handle')
      .call(d3.drag()
      .on('drag', handling))
      .on("mouseover", handleHovering) 

    d3.selectAll('.surface')
      .on('dblclick', makeSomethingWhenDoubleClicked)


    d3.selectAll(".surface")
      .transition()
      .duration(400)
      .style("fill", "#fcda7c");

    d3.selectAll('.surface').on("click", clicked )
}

function clicked() {
  console.log('click')
}

function dragStarted () {
  console.log('start')
}

function dragRoom (d) {
  console.log('drag')

  d3.select(this).raise().style('cursor', 'grabbing')

  let index = rooms.findIndex(x => x.id === d.id);

  let moveX = d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX
  let moveY = d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY

  if (index >= 0) {
    rooms[index] = { 
      id : rooms[index].id,
      w : rooms[index].w,
      h : rooms[index].h,
      tx : rooms[index].tx +moveX, 
      ty : rooms[index].ty +moveY
    }
  }
  drawIt(rooms)
}

function handling() {
  let roomId = d3.event.subject.id

  d3.select(this)
  .attr("x", parseInt(this.getAttribute('x'), 10) + d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX ) 
  .attr("y", parseInt(this.getAttribute('y'), 10) + d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY )

  let index = rooms.findIndex( (e) => e.id === roomId)

  if (this.getAttribute('class') === 'handle w') {
    rooms[index].tx = rooms[index].tx + d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX
    rooms[index].w = rooms[index].w - d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX
  } else if (this.getAttribute('class') === 'handle e') {
    rooms[index].tx = rooms[index].tx
    rooms[index].w = rooms[index].w + d3.event.sourceEvent.movementX
  } else if (this.getAttribute('class') === 'handle s') {
    rooms[index].ty = rooms[index].ty
    rooms[index].h = rooms[index].h + d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY
  } else if (this.getAttribute('class') === 'handle n') {
    rooms[index].ty = rooms[index].ty + d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY
    rooms[index].h = rooms[index].h - d3.event.sourceEvent.movementY
  } 
  drawIt(rooms)
}

function makeSomethingWhenDoubleClicked(d) {
  let room = d3.event.srcElement
  console.log(room)
  d3.selectAll('.back').classed('selected', false)
  d3.select(room).classed('selected', true)
}

function release(d) {
  console.log("release")
  let index = rooms.findIndex(x => x.id === d.id);

  for (let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) {

    if (rooms[index] !== rooms[i]) {
      if (( rooms[index].tx + rooms[index].w) - rooms[i].tx < 20 && ( rooms[index].tx + rooms[index].w) - rooms[i].tx > -20 ) {
        rooms[index].tx = rooms[i].tx - rooms[index].w-5
      }
      if (Math.abs((rooms[index].tx + rooms[index].w) - (rooms[i].tx + rooms[i].w)) < 20) {
        rooms[index].tx = rooms[i].tx + rooms[i].w - rooms[index].w 
      }
      if (rooms[index].tx - rooms[i].tx < 20 && rooms[index].tx - rooms[i].tx > -20) {
        rooms[index].tx = rooms[i].tx
      }  
      if (rooms[index].tx - (rooms[i].tx + rooms[i].w) < 20 && rooms[index].tx - (rooms[i].tx + rooms[i].w) > -20 ) {
        rooms[index].tx = rooms[i].tx + rooms[i].w + 5
      }
      if (Math.abs(rooms[index].ty - rooms[i].ty) < 20) {
        rooms[index].ty = rooms[i].ty
      }
      if (Math.abs(rooms[index].ty - (rooms[i].ty + rooms[i].h)) < 20) {
        rooms[index].ty = rooms[i].ty + rooms[i].h +5
      }
      if (Math.abs((rooms[index].ty + rooms[index].h) - rooms[i].ty) < 20) {
        rooms[index].ty = rooms[i].ty - rooms[index].h -5
      }
      if (Math.abs((rooms[index].ty + rooms[index].h) - (rooms[i].ty + rooms[i].h)) < 20) {
        rooms[index].ty = rooms[i].ty + rooms[i].h - rooms[index].h
      }
     }
  }
  drawIt(rooms)
}

plan.on("dblclick", () => makeRoom())

function makeRoom() {
  console.log(this)
  let myRect = {
    id : Math.random(),
    w : 100,
    h : 100,
    tx : 100,
    ty : 100,
    class : ""
  }

  rooms = [ ...rooms, myRect]

  drawIt(rooms)
}

function handleHovering() {
  if (this.getAttribute("class") === "handle w" || this.getAttribute("class") === "handle e") {
    d3.select(this).style('cursor', 'e-resize')
  } else {
    d3.select(this).style('cursor', 'n-resize')
  }
}
```

style.css

```
body { margin:0;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0; }

svg { width:100%; height: 100% }

.foo { fill: #98fad8}

.selected {
      fill : #82ff88;
    }

.popup {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    /*display: none;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    right: 115px;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I found a topic on StackOverflow [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562548/d3-v4-drag-clickdistance-doesnt-seem-to-have-any-effect) Here, the author seems to make something similar to what i am doing : re-rendering everything after each data changes. He uses a setTimeout method to delay the rerendering, making space for the mouseup to trigger the click event. BUT... this means that my drag function is still triggered. Why not, but this seems to be not the cleanest way...

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/click-vs-drag

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this link. I've read it already. And I don't really understand it. I read "don't re-append the element on drag 'start', but I think I am not doing it until drag 'drag' with my drawIt function... He's talking about a bring-to-front method. Is this made calling raise() I can't see the point here ?